# Which is faster from querying posts in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to ask which is faster regarding querying posts in wordpress.

Is it better to create a new table for new data then make a custom SELECT statements or is it better to use the default wp_posts and wp_postmeta table and use the built in query functions of wordpress?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to store there and whether the indexes on the tables in question make sense. Technically, that is. Practically speaking, it's not going to matter unless you are doing something either really complex or really illogical. Even more practically speaking, it's impossible to answer this question without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Im trying to make a plugin like a inventory system and would like to ask first before designing the database. Im trying to make it AJAX all functions like pagination, search, adding of product like that, and it will matter in performance so i really like to know first to avoid problem in future when there will be a lot of data stored

Comment: Well, that's the kind of data that is unlikely to fit well in the posts or metadata tables. Some self-proclaimed purists will insist that you should use custom post types for this, but that will be like fitting a square peg into a round hole. Instead, create tables that make sense for your data and create proper indexes for whatever queries you need to do. With proper indexes, it won't be slower, but will almost certainly be faster, and it will be much easier to read your code and understand what you're doing.

Comment: ok thank you for the info, but i would like to know which is faster regarding querying data in database when using wordpress.

Comment: Like I said, for what you are describing, using your own tables will be faster. It will not be slower, and is likely to be much faster, *provided you do it correctly*. It's certainly possible to get horrible results with either approach if you don't do things correctly.

Comment: So custom mysql SELECT statements is better than the built in query functions of wordpress?

Comment: It's not about the SELECT statements themselves; it's about how you store the data. It's unlikely that you can store data for an inventory system in the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables in a way that makes any sense. As a result, the SELECT queries you would run would probably be slow and awkward (not to mention hard to write). *If you know what you're doing and use proper indexes*, then creating your own tables and your own queries is the way to go. If not, then you probably are going to need help with this part of your plugin, whichever way you go.

Comment: Note: I am not saying write your own database connection and query functions. You can still use the query *functions* of WordPress, whichever way you do this.

Answer (score 0):

For inventory you should make your own table, so that operations on those data will be more or less independent of WordPress and when you want to remove that you can remove that easily without affecting other settings. And, yes, you should use built-in query functions or you can use wp_query() for operations. Read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/most-efficient-way-to-get-posts-with-postmeta/39932#39932).
I hope this will clarify your ideas.

Comment: well, this plugin is just for one site. custom mysql SELECT statements is better than the built in query functions of wordpress?

Comment: It is some how difficult to answer as It depends upon how your table is build and how you are querying, wp_query is simpler to use as compare to your custom query and more or less you can say It is just a wrapper , If you are good with SQL query . so if you will use mySql SELECT correctly, It will be faster as It will be independent of your wordpress main query .

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to use the default wp_posts and wp_postmeta table because that are default tables and fetching data from that tables with wp function is more efficient if you want to create your custom post type so there is one plugin CUSTOM POST TYPE by using this you can create a custom post type into admin and you need not to do any coding for this and it will be showing on front end as normal post are showing.
Suppose you want to create homepageslider post type so you just need to create it into custom post type and on front end you can do like below code :-

```
<?
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'homepageslide');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$posttitle = $post->post_title;
?>
      <div onclick="window.location='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'home_page_slide_link', true); ?>'" style="cursor:pointer" data-iview:thumbnail="<? echo $image_url ?>" data-iview:image="<? echo $image_url ?>">
        <div class="iview-caption caption1" data-x="100" data-y="300" data-transition="expandDown">
          <h2> <? echo substr($post->post_title,0,25); ?></h2>
          <p><? echo $post->post_content; ?> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <? endwhile; ?>
```

I think now it will helpfull.
Here is the link to download Custom Post Type Plugin :
[Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

Comment: You should edit this answer to use sentences and make it objective, not opinion-based.